# Does `print()` delay in some consoles where `stdout.flush` doesn't?

Tags: python, stdout, flush, sys

I'm working on an open source python library that uses a `verbose_print` command to log outputs in the console. Currently it looks like this:

```
def sys_write_flush(s):
    """ Writes and flushes without delay a text in the console """
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()


def verbose_print(verbose, s):
    """ Only prints s (with sys_write_flush) if verbose is True."""
    if verbose:
        sys_write_flush(s)
```

I proposed a change that looks like this:

```
def verbose_print(verbose, *args):
    """ Prints everything passed except the first argument if verbose is True."""
    if verbose:
        print(*args)
```

Apart from the fact that it fails on Python 2 (bonus point for fixing this!), I thought that this would be better and more idiomatic. The advantages are, that you can treat `verbose_print` exactly like `print`, except that the first argument has to be `True` or `False`.

The repo owner replied with this message:

> I should have documented this one, but basically the issue was that in
> some consoles (and in the IPython notebook, at least at the time),
> "print" commands get delayed, while stdout.flush are instantaneous, so
> my method was better at providing feedback.
>
> I would be against changing it to print unless it solves some known
> issues.

Is this still a valid concern?  Would `print()` followed by `sys.stdout.flush()` avoid the delay?  Are there any better ways to write this?

[Source](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/485)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the docs:

> `print` evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting
> object to *standard output*.

> *Standard output* is defined as the file object named `stdout` in the
> built-in module `sys`.  If no such object exists, or if it does not
> have a `write()` method, a `RuntimeError` exception is raised.

According to this, `print` writes to `sys.stdout`, so, yes, doing a `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print`ing will have the same effect as `flush`ing after `sys.stdout.write`-ing.

---

The syntax `print(*a)` fails in Python 2 because `print` isn't a function, but a *statement*, and that `fun(*stuff)` construct is only applicable to functions.

In Python 3 `print(*a)` passes whatever `a` contains to the function `print` *as separate arguments*, but this is equal to passing a big string:

```
separator = ' '
print separator.join(map(str, iterable))
```

So, your code could look like this:

```
def verbose_print(verbose, *args):
    """ Prints everything passed except the first argument if verbose is True."""
    if verbose:
        print " ".join(map(str, args))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Although I don't see why this can be faster or more readable than the original.